# Finding consecutive numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $p, q, r, s, t$ are consecutive numbers and  $p!+q!+r!+s^2=t^2$, then what are the values of $p, q, r, s$ and $ t$?

My try:

By brute force I got that $p=1$. But how to prove this more mathematically?

Comment: Do you have that $p\leq q \leq r \leq s \leq t$, or are they unordered?

Comment: Consecutive in the sense that $p=1,q=2,r=3,s=4,t=5$.

Comment: @Lohith-kumar No, he means in general, do we have that $q=p+1,r=p+2,s=p+3,t=p+4$?

Comment: Yes, @mrnovice that's what we have. Thanks for clearing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:
Note that  $t>s$  from the equation, so that  $q=p+1$,  $r=p+2$,  $s=p+3$, and  $t=p+4$. Rewriting the given equation as

$$p!(1+(p+1)+(p+1)(p+2))=t^2−s^2=t+s=2p+7,$$
we see that  $p∣7$. Hence  $p=1$  or  $p=7$. But  $p!>p(p−1)>2p−7$  for  $p=7$.

Comment: Minor quibble:  $p!\mid 2p+7$ for $p=0$ also, but $0\not\mid7$.  (That is, I think you need to note that $1+(0+1)+(0+1)(0+2)\not=2\cdot0+7$.)

Answer (score 1):

$$p!+q!+r!+s^2=t^2$$

$$p!(1+ q + qr) =(t - s)(s+t) = s + t$$

Since $s + t$ is odd,

both $p!$ and $(1+ q + qr)$ should be odd,

if $p!$ is odd then $p = 1$ because only odd factorial is $1!$

Comment: $s+t$ is odd because either $s$ or $t$ is is odd and other is even, so $2n + 2n +1 = 4n + 1$ which is odd.

Comment: And I forgot about $0!$ as always, which is also odd. But $1 + 1+ 2+9  = 14 \ne 16$,

Answer (score 1):

Without assuming that $p,q,r,s,t$ are in ascending order, we can still limit the possible solutions to effectively the one given. I'll use the form $p!+q!+r!=t^2-s^2$

First notice that one of the factorials on the LHS must be within $2$ of $t$, and $5!>7^2$ so certainly $t<7$ and the largest of $p,q,r$ is less than $5$.

So our options then are $A=\{2,3,4,5,6\}$, $B=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and if we allow zero, $C=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

For set $A$, $2!+3!+4! = 30 > 6^2-5^2$ will not work.

For set $B$,  $1!+2!+3!=9 = 5^2-4^2$ is good. Otherwise we would have $4!$ on the LHS and the difference of squares would not be feasible. So we get $\{p,q,r\}=\{1,2,3\}, s=4,t=5$

For set $C$,  $0!+1!+2!=4<4^2-3^2$; $0!+1!+3!=8<4^2-2^2$; $0!+2!+3!=9<4^2-1^2$ so there is no feasible solution there either.

Comment: This is the real answer.